# How do I use NHibernate with Rx.NET?

Tags: nhibernate, rx.net

I'm looking through blogs and reactivex.net books but am having a hard time seeing how to create an observable stream from NHibernate queries. In RxJava I would use Observable.fromCallable - or maybe that's not even the best way. I know I need to open a stateless stream from a query's results but the syntax on how to do that eludes me.

What is the syntax to create an Observable stream from an NHibernate query? Also, if different, how to issue a persist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Rx exists to simplify asynchronous programming I'm assuming that your NHibernate (I've never used it) query is asynchronous and returns a `Task`. Rx makes it really easy to turn the `Task` into an observable using `ToObservable()`.

So it may look something like this:

```
 var observable = 
     session
         .CreateCriteria<Product>()
         .ListAsync<Product>()
         .ToObservable();
```

The observable will emit the query results when the query completes or throw an exception if something goes awry.

You can read more about `ToObservable()` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211785%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)